# How to send attachment from Laravel storage app to email via PHPmailer

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

I have tried to send attachments by accessing files from the storage app that I am uploading from the form and send it to email using phpMailer but in vain.

After the files being uploaded from the form, it is stored in **storage/app/docs**
The body content is sending but the attachment is not, Kindly help

**controller function**

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer(); // create a n
$mail->SMTPDebug  = false; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host       = "server1.web-hosting.com";
$mail->Port       = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "support@example.com";
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("support@example.com", $receiver_name);

$file = $request->file('filenames');
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filename_string = time().'.'.$filename;

$path = $file->storeAs('docs', $filename_string);


$mail->AddAttachment($path,$filename_string);
$mail->Subject = 'Order No #'.$paw.'- Premium Article Writers
';
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
$mail->Body    = $text;



$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);

$mail->Send();
}
else
{
echo "No data Was posted nor sent to database, Contact administrator for help- info@premiumarticlewriters.com";
}
```

Comment: have you checked this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#attaching-files-from-disk

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes, I have tried I get this error `Method App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::attachFromStorage does not exist.`